# Why I can't read this web api from marvel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I have been working with web api and it has been fine. Now I'm trying to use the Marvel's api and I have an error.
This is the code I've been using for all the web apis

```
 function getPosts(){
         fetch('http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?ts=1&apikey=b5dd158dd0e856443db7fb726fbc6bc9&hash=80182fcb24c6426319114b9e34eafed6')
         .then((res) => res.json())
         .then((info) => {
             let output = '<h2 class="mb-4"> Posts </h2>';
             info.forEach(function(post){
                 output +=  `
                 <div class="card card-body mb-3">
                     <h3>${post.data.results.title}</h3>
                 </div>                                
                 `;
             });
             document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
         })
     }
```

This is the error I get
[image]

Comment: info may be an object whoch doesn't have a .forEach function

Comment: Your response is an object with the key `data` which is an object with the key `results` which is an array that you want to use for looping.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson how can I fix that I'm a student I'm just learning rn

Answer (score 4):

You need to access the actual array of the results.
You are applying forEach to an object, forEach only operates over arrays 
[mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
the actual array is in *info.data.results*

example, displaying the titles:

```
 function getPosts(){
     fetch('//gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?ts=1&apikey=b5dd158dd0e856443db7fb726fbc6bc9&hash=80182fcb24c6426319114b9e34eafed6')
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((info) => {
        info.data['results'].forEach( data => {
          console.log(data.title);
        });
     })
 }
```

Comment: You should share your example in a platform like https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla, 
or jsbin.com , once you have your code there, I can help better
Also, I recommend you read about event delegation

Comment: This is the code I'm using https://codesandbox.io/s/4wojv82zn0?fontsize=14 The first like button is the only one with the count

Comment: @LuisFernandoBadelMéndez check the url, remove the protocol part so it works, https://codesandbox.io/s/ox74319qm6, you have to fix the likes part

Comment: the error was the "likes" part, the other thing I fixed it yestarday

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code here you can get your title and you could append this title in any html tag wherever you want

```
$.get('http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?ts=1&apikey=b5dd158dd0e856443db7fb726fbc6bc9&hash=80182fcb24c6426319114b9e34eafed6',function(dataObject){
var results=dataObject;
var data=results.data.results;
    $.each(data,function(index,item){
    var title=item.title;
     console.log(title);
    });
});
```

Comment: you can add by this code ` $(document).on('click','your selector',function(){
//put your code here
}); `

Comment: how can I make a good counter for each like button? I allwats get the first button with the counter check my code https://codesandbox.io/s/ox74319qm6